# Replace strings in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string that consists of tags `<p> </p>` and I want to replace them by `<br />`, but whenever I try using `str_replace()` it does not do so.

Is there any solution to it? Any other possible way to do it?

```
   $string="<p> This is one para </p> <p> This is second </p>";
```

Using:

```
   str_replace("</p> <p>","<br />",$string> nothing gets replaced.
```

Comment: You really need to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). What have you tried? What is the problem, anyway - I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Show your code and explain what *does not do so* means, do you get: `PHP warning: Code does not do so on line xx` ?

Comment: Have edited accordingly

Comment: 1) First you would need to get the syntax right otherwise nothing is going to run 2) Take a look at the manual page for `str_replace()` and look what arguments `str_replace()` can take

Comment: [The code you've posted works exactly as it should](http://ideone.com/nJFqMh). Check that the space between `</p>` and `<p>` really is a single space

Comment: @MariumMalik Do you assign the return value of the function back to the string?

Comment: Use preg_replace to search for: 1) </p>, 2) whitespace, linebreak (\n,\r), (if any at all, it might not allways be something in between the end and start tag)  2) <p>. I dont know the specific regular expression, but i think this is a good hint to continue with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
 <?php

    $string = "<p> This is one para </p> <p> This is second </p>";

    $searchArray = array(
        '<p>'
      , '</p>'
    );

    $replaceArray = array(
        ''
      , '<br />'
    );

    var_dump( str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $string) );

?>
```

Output

```
string(47) " This is one para <br />  This is second <br />"
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace` looks for an exact match, and replaces it. There is no `"<p> </p>"` in your string, and so it will never match. The behaviour you seem to be expecting is this:

If the string contains *these* substrings, replace them with *this*. Even if `str_replace` did behave that way, how would it know where to put the replacement?

I believe this is your intent;

```
$needles = array("<p>" => "",
                 "</p>" => "</br>");

$string = "<p> This is one para </p> <p> This is second </p>";

$match = true;

foreach($needles as $find => $replace)
{
    if(strpos($string, $find) === false)
    {
       $match = false;
    }
}
if($match)
{
    foreach($needles as $find => $replace)
    {
        $string = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
    }  

}

echo $string;
```

If the string matches *all* of the keys in `$needles`, it will replace them with the corresponding values in `$needles`. If you're going to be doing a lot more HTML manipulation however, then regular expressions using `preg_replace` would be a better approach.